# Duplicate records after drag & drop and AJAX save

Tags: javascript, ajax, duplicates

I'm struggling with a conceptual issue on the web app I'm working on.
The app allows users to drag & drop DOM element (like a note, a list, an image).
You drag elements from a menu to a sort of sheet of paper.
Once you drop one, the app makes an AJAX call to the server to save that element (position, color, etc...)
The server answers with an id which is then saved to the DOM element as its id attribute.
When you move that element again, the same AJAX call is made but with its id.

The problem though, is that if I quickly drop a new element on the drop zone then move it again, it creates duplicate entries because the first AJAX call hasn't finished yet that the second one is made without id (since it has to come from the server).

Here's a simplified sample of javascript code to save elements :

```
function saveObject(object,action){

    var params = {
        x : object.position().left,
        y : object.position().top,
        w : object.width(),
        h : object.height(),
     };

    if(object.attr("id")){
         params.id = object.attr("id");
    }

    $.post("/save_object",params,function(data){
        if(data.success){
            object.attr("id",data.data);
        }
    });

}
```

Server-side, I just check for an id then I either run a "create" function or "modify" function with the id.

This is very specific, I've looked a lot of post about ajax duplication but setting a flag won't help here. I can't block AJAX request from being made because it's supposed not to block any UI elements and I don't want to lose any save events. I have some restriction to stick to because this page is dynamic and users on the same page see each other user's events.

I would be thankful for any answer at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few different ways you can go about solving this issue, I'll let you choose as one may be more suitable for your application.

Option one would be to queue the requests to the server by storing them inside an array. you would then have some logic that would send a request one by one.

Option two would be to move the object id inception onto the client side by using GUID's rather than auto-incrementing ID's. You could then save these to the server without worry of duplication or overwriting. I would also suggest using an MVC to keep the logic organised, backbone.js for example.

Comment: problem with option 2 is that the app, as it works now with the entire infrastructure, can't be refactor that way. Option 1 would kind of make the deal but I'll probably lose responsiveness and dynamism in the app doing it that way. Of course, you guys don't see everything here but I can't detail it more unfortunately :(

Comment: I think if you just rewrite your app to accept the ID from the client instead of create an ID on the server, you should be ok. I doubt that would be a massive change, though I could be wrong.

Comment: problem is we have mobile apps working that way too and we can't afford to change that because it's DB changes as well as server and app

Comment: O, I'd suggest option one then. In regards to your worries with responsiveness I highly doubt there will be any noticeable affect. I don't think the user would be dragging the shapes into the grid that fast as to cause a back log of requests.

Comment: I'll try and see if I can do something conclusive

Answer (score 0):

to make this work seamlessly...

1.you will have to block the drag and drop functionality till the earlier request has finished

OR

2.abort the earlier request if a new request is made.

You can have a queuing logic...you can store all your requests in an array...an array of xmlHTTP objects.
You can then either choose to send ajax requests in a queue or just send one request at a time and discard all the other requests in the meantime.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the second point ? The first one is absolutely not an option here. I definitively can't block requests from being made with the actual app mechanics.